Install a file to Program data folder using Visual Studio 2022 Setup project
I am creating a installation setup for a VB.Net windows application using Visual Studio 2022. I want to place a MS Access database in the C:\ProgramData\ApplicationName folder. So I created a custom folder in the setup project by right click on File System on Target Machine. I want to set the Default Location of this custom folder to C:\ProgramData\ApplicationName folder. So from the below shown picture, which option I have to choose.

